# PHP-FPM+Nginx set keepalive cause response error?

Tags: php, docker, nginx, keep-alive, fpm

I set up PHP-FPM and Nginx to maintain persistent connections. However, in high concurrency scenarios, the responses are incorrect, causing the frontend to display the source code of the webpage directly. After testing, I discovered that the erroneous pages contain content from other pages, and there are no blank lines in the request response and response bodies.

```
upstream fpm {
    server we-fpm:18074;
    keepalive 32;
}
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$)
{
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass fpm;
    ...
}
```

In high concurrency scenarios, sometimes the following responses may occur(curl), treating the response body as the response header.:

```
> GET /xxxxx/xxxx/xxxx HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8074
> Accept: */*
> User-Agent: 20230520194633
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Sat, 20 May 2023 11:46:33 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< <!DOCTYPE html>:
< <html lang="en">:

        p {
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
===== the page i don't kown how come ====
</script>
</body>
</htmlX-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.30
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=5fvq4esv0v9ho3k66ug7nfmrcd; path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 20 May 2023 11:46:33 GMT

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
====the page i want===
</html>
```

correct response is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
====the page i want===
</html>
```

I don't know how the following content came about.

```
< <!DOCTYPE html>:
< <html lang="en">:

        p {
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
...
</script>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Solution: Don't use persistent connections :)

Comment: Can you please tell me what the issue is?